# Fix encoding issue

Tags: curl, unicode, encoding, utf-8, iconv

I used cURL to scrape some reviews for a little experiment. This worked mostly fine, except for some files that have encoding issues.

In particular, there are *no* problems with:

- files without any special characters
- files with exotic character sets (Chinese, Japanese, Korean, etc)

However, these do have problems:

- files with only a few special characters

For example, an Italian text:

```
mi sono fatto dare un menÃ¹ classico per vedere i loro piatti che solitamente offrono e penso proprio di tornarci
```

In this particular case Ã¹ should be ù. The 'file' utility tells me the file is indeed a UTF-8 file: 'HTML document, UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines'. But vim and other editors show the character incorrectly.

I would like to understand the root cause of the issue. Did cURL guess the encoding of the original HTML incorrectly and saved the single character as two UTF8 characters? Is there any way to force cURL to do the right thing?

Is there an automated way of detecting this issue in a bunch of files? I would prefer not redownloading all the files.

Is there an automated way of fixing this issue? I.e., replace Ã¹ by ù (and other similar issues) and save as UTF8? The closest I came was using iconv:

```
iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT file
```

This fixes the issue but saves the file as ISO-8859-1 (which is not what I want). I'm also not sure if this would fix the issue for each encoding error.

A hexdump of the above sentence:

```
0000000 696d 7320 6e6f 206f 6166 7474 206f 6164
0000010 6572 7520 206e 656d c36e c283 20b9 6c63
0000020 7361 6973 6f63 7020 7265 7620 6465 7265
0000030 2065 2069 6f6c 6f72 7020 6169 7474 2069
0000040 6863 2065 6f73 696c 6174 656d 746e 2065
0000050 666f 7266 6e6f 206f 2065 6570 736e 206f
0000060 7270 706f 6972 206f 6964 7420 726f 616e
0000070 6372 0a69                              
0000074
```

Hexdump of the same sentence after inconv command above:

```
0000000 696d 7320 6e6f 206f 6166 7474 206f 6164
0000010 6572 7520 206e 656d c36e 20b9 6c63 7361
0000020 6973 6f63 7020 7265 7620 6465 7265 2065
0000030 2069 6f6c 6f72 7020 6169 7474 2069 6863
0000040 2065 6f73 696c 6174 656d 746e 2065 666f
0000050 7266 6e6f 206f 2065 6570 736e 206f 7270
0000060 706f 6972 206f 6964 7420 726f 616e 6372
0000070 0a69                                   
0000072
```

Comment: That looks like UTF-8 looked at in a program that doesn't recognize the text as UTF-8. What are you using to look at the file?

Comment: Vim, but I have tried a few other editors as well. I have also used ':set fileencoding=utf-8' to make sure that it was not an editor issue.

Comment: Not sure what is wrong then. If you open it in an editor and force it to treat it as UTF-8, it's still displayed incorrectly? You are 100% sure? It could be that the file was misinterpreted along the way, but then you shouldn't be able to fix it using iconv I think. It might be worth looking at the headers that get sent by the site you're scraping, see whether it's erroneously declaring a single-byte encoding but sending UTF-8

Comment: I added a hexdump of the sentence...

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you've got a few minor issues that have compounded each other:

1. Your terminal emulation is set to "Windows-1252" or "ISO-8859-1". It should be set to "UTF-8".
2. You've copied and pasted the output into another file to perform a hex dump. This copies the text as rendered on screen. The hex dump seems to contain additional control characters which may have come from the clipboard.
3. Your hex dump is in big endian mode, which makes it difficult to see words or decode UTF-8 by eye.

When I fetch "http://www.tripadvisor.it/ShowUserReviews-g187849-d2263221-r233247966-Sant_Eustorgio-Milan_Lombardy.html", with my terminal set to "UTF-8" and my locale set to "en_GB.UTF-8" (You should set it to which ever region is correct for you but ensure it ends in ".UTF-8"), the file is correctly saved as UTF-8 and displays in `vim`, `cat` and `less`.

Comment: Ditto, looks ok to me, too.

Comment: Ok, so the root cause was some post-processing I did using [pup](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup) without the '--charset utf8' flag. I grep'ed for 'Ã' and simply redownloaded these files.

Answer (score 0):

I think `set fileencoding=utf-8` is the wrong option for you, as it sets the encoding for the written file. The displayed encoding is set with `set encoding=utf-8`, so you should try this instead.

Comment: You're absolutely right that the correct command is ':set encoding=UTF-8'. Unfortunately, however, it doesn't solve the issue at hand.